# Nota blanca translation

Tags: traducción

In Enrique González Martínez´poem, *Tuércele el cuello al cisne de engañoso plumaje*, there is a line that makes me wonder if an alternate translation should be used. The line is:

*que da su nota blanca al azul de la fuente;*

and it comes directly after the first line (that is the title of the poem).

It usually gets translated as:

Wring the swan’s neck who with deceiving plumage
inscribes his whiteness on the azure stream;

I don't think this is in keeping with the rest of the poem.  is way too kind to the swan who in this poem is decidedly not treated kindly.

Could the *nota blanca* be a reference to the short harsh sound a swan makes? Its trumpeting? I thought I saw somewhere that a *nota blanca* was a 1/16th note.

Comment: I don't think "nota" refers to the sound. There might be some irony, because the whiteness looks too simple against the deep blue. When we say in Spanish "dar la nota" we generally refer to something negative, meaning "to stand out" in a negative way.

Comment: Agreed, I interpret it as the gimmick way the swan has to show its superfluous becoming in front of the hidden, not so charming and discreet wisdom of the owl.

Comment: It's fine. gives a white note to the blue of the fountain. I can't see the poem but that translation is truly awful. Colors often are said to have notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Que tal?,  El poema completo aparece de forma siguiente;

---

**Tuércele el cuello al cisne de engañoso plumaje**

---

Tuércele el cuello al cisne de engañoso plumaje

**que da su nota blanca al azul de la fuente;**

él pasea su gracia no más, pero no siente

el alma de las cosas ni la voz del paisaje.

Huye de toda forma y de todo lenguaje

que no vayan acordes con el ritmo latente

de la vida profunda... y adora intensamente

la vida, y que la vida comprenda tu homenaje.

Mira al sapiente búho cómo tiende las alas

desde el Olimpo, deja el regazo de Palas

y posa en aquel árbol el vuelo taciturno...

Él no tiene la gracia del cisne, mas su inquieta

pupila, que se clava en la sombra, interpreta

el misterioso libro del silencio nocturno.

---

**la nota blanca**;

*Suele traducirse como:

Torcerle el cuello al cisne que con plumaje engañoso

inscribe su blancura en el arroyo azul;*

---

Existen varias partes que no capto muy bien;

- No se porque dices "*torcerle el cuello*" en forma impersonal, cuando esta hablando en imperativo de segunda persona?. Tuércele el cuello.
- Por otro lado, no se de donde salió el arroyo azul, solo habla de una *fuente*, referido a ese tipo de estanques con fuentes que hay en los parques.
- Por último, *inscribe su blancura*, ese verbo, inscribir, se utiliza cuando algo se introduce dentro de algo, cuando algo se graba con, en ó sobre algo de manera profunda, tomando contacto.

Al utilizar la expresión "*dando su nota blanca*" esta describiendo la imagen blanca de su sinuoso, lánguido y hermoso cuello, reflejada sobre (el agua) azul de la fuente, como una pincelada de la propia belleza que en el agua destella y que a la vez es capaz de verse. Así pues dar "*una nota de color*", un matiz, en este caso el blanco y en este contexto, no es "inscribe su blancura", eso sería meter su blancura "dentro" del agua", más bien es todo lo contrario, no toma contacto con el agua, solo observamos el brillo blanco que se refleja superficialmente y de forma efímera. Como una imagen que permanece sobre el lecho del agua azul desdibujando continuamente las formas blancas de lo que en ella se refleja, pero intuyendo a la vez la belleza de las mismas.

El poema se encuentra en la última parte del movimiento literario llamado Modernista, haciendo en este caso una comparación, "*plumaje engañoso*", entre el cisne....aquí representa las formas, el estilo, la belleza...y el otro protagonista, el búho, que es todo lo contrarío, es decir, se pueden decir cosas más intensas, importantes y profundas sin tener tanto en cuenta las formas y las normas modernistas.

Espero te haya ayudado, aunque tarde. Saludos. Diego M.

Answer (score 6):

A "[(nota) blanca](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blanca_(m%C3%BAsica))" is a half note, not a 1/16th note. It would not be used to refer to a short sound.

We can never be sure what Enrique González Martínez meant, but "nota blanca" in the poem is likely to refer to the white color, because it is compared to the blue stream (or fountain). In his article [1], the poet [Niall Binns](https://www.ucm.es/literaturashispanicas/niall-binns) writes the following about Enrique González Martínez's poem:

> Es decir, ese plumaje que daba su nota blanca
> al azul de la frente, pretendía trascender en cada una de las significaciones
> no decorativas que distinguió Salinas: [...]; intentaba representar la virtud en su blancura [...]

i.e., what gives the "nota blanca" to the stream are the swan's feathers. This means that Niall Binns indeed believes "nota blanca" to refer to the white color.

---

<sub>[1] Niall Binns, "Lecturas, malas lecturas y parodias: desplumando el cisne rubendariano (Enrique González Martínez, Delmira Agustini, Vicente Huidobro, Nicanor Parra)", available [online](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/lecturas-malas-lecturas-y-parodias-desplumando-el-cisne-rubendariano-enrique-gonzalez-martinez-delmira-agustini-vicente-huidobro-nicanor-parra/html/3b0d64b9-2ec2-4449-8253-a3c7fe7913f9_3.html).</sub>